# Ask for SYSTEM-permission on Android M?

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

The desciption for the new permission-model on Android M doesn't state what happens with SYSTEM-permissions which are granted only for app under /system/priv-app normally:

> Limited Permissions Granted at Install Time: When the user installs or updates the app, the system grants the app all permissions listed in the manifest that fall under PROTECTION_NORMAL. For example, alarm clock and internet permissions fall under PROTECTION_NORMAL, so they are automatically granted at install time. For more information about how normal permissions are handled, see Normal Permissions.
>   The system may also grant the app signature permissions, as described in System components and signature permissions. The user is not prompted to grant any permissions at install time.
>   User Grants Permissions at Run-Time: When the app requests a permission, the system shows a dialog to the user, then calls the app's callback function to notify it whether the user granted the permission.

Can someone say if it's possible to ask the user for SYSTEM-permissions like "CAPTURE_REMOTE_SUBMIX" or so in Android M, even not being installed as a system-app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no system permissions listed in [the table of permissions that are affected by the runtime permission system](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#check-for-permission).

Comment: Thanks for your fast feedback, really appreciate it :)